# cant get signal to connect to slot in PyQT5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

This is my first post so hi to everyone!  So i am trying to learn Python 3.8 and PyQT5 and im using Spyder.  I have been working my way through a tutorial on MVC programming and decided to write my own very basic GUI with a controller (havent got to the model yet!).  However i am completely stuck with understanding why i cant use the connect command to run a function in the controller class(ive even seen this in the tutorial but cant figure what ive done wrong).

The full code is below.

In the class Ctrl the function  `_connectSignals(self)` should be connecting the signals and the slots but:

```
self._view.hi.clicked.connect(self._calculateResult)
```

doesnt call the _calculateResult function (nothing happens when the button is clicked, however if i change it to:

```
self._view.hi.clicked.connect(self._view.setDisplayText)
```

it works fine and the function is called when the button is pressed.

Why cant i call the _calculateResult function inside the ctrl class and use this to call _view.setDisplayText?

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

thanks

Matt

```
import sys

# Import QApplication and the required widgets from PyQt5.QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

# Create a subclass of QMainWindow to setup the GUI
class PyUi(QMainWindow):
    """View (GUI)."""

    def __init__(self):
        """View initializer."""
        super().__init__()
        # Set some main window's properties
        self.setWindowTitle("copy")
        self.setFixedSize(100,100)
        # Set the central widget and the general layout
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        # self._centralWidget = QPushButton('copy')
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        # # Create the display and the buttons
        self._createDisplay()

    def _createDisplay(self):
        """Create the display."""
        # # Create button
        self.hi = QPushButton('Hi')
        # # Set output
        self.write = QLineEdit()
        self.write.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.write.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.write.setReadOnly(True)
 
        # Add the display to the general layout
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.hi)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.write)
        
    def setDisplayText(self):
        """Set display's text."""

        self.write.setText('Hello to you too')
    
# Create a Controller class
class Ctrl:
    """Controller."""

    def __init__(self, view):
        """Controller initializer."""
        self._view = view
        # Connect signals and slots
        self._connectSignals()

    def _calculateResult(self):
        """Evaluate expressions."""
        self._view.setDisplayText()

    def _connectSignals(self):

        self._view.hi.clicked.connect(self._calculateResult) # doesnt work
       # self._view.hi.clicked.connect(self._view.setDisplayText) # works

# Client code
def main():
    """Main function."""
    # Create an instance of `QApplication`
    py = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Show GUI
    view = PyUi()
    view.show()
    # Create instances of the model and the controller
    Ctrl(view=view)
    # Execute main loop
    sys.exit(py.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Note that `self._calculateResult` is not a part of your `view` object. I don't know the specifics of `pyqt` but it stands to reason that the class needs the connection to be a part of the class

Comment: Try assigning the `Ctrl` instance to a variable: `ctrl = Ctrl(view=view)`.  My guess is that the `connect` statement is working fine but the `Ctrl` instance is being destroyed immediately after construction thus removing that connection.  The other connection is okay because it doesn't refer to the `Ctrl` instance in any way.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of [PyQt5 buttons not connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143060/pyqt5-buttons-not-connecting)

Comment: Thanks musicamante i didnt see this post!  I tried the suggestion in that post but using Ctrl = Ctrl(view=view) resulted in and error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Ctrl' referenced before assignment.  I think this is something to do with self referring to Ctrl or UI but im not sure (sorry very new to this!).  Can this issue be explained with and example?? thanks

Comment: ok i think i Figure it out.  I was trying to use Ctrl not ctrl for the variable as suggested by G. M. and in the other post.  I learned something about global variables in the process though!